# ECS - Container cannot pull public image from Docker Hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, dockerhub

When deploying Task in ECS Cluster with a public repo Docker Hub, the task always Stopped with this error in the Task Container:

```
Stopped reason
Cannotpullcontainererror: 
    pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): 
        failed to resolve ref docker.io/username/repo: 
            failed to do request: 
                Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/username/repo/manifests/latest": 
                    dial tcp 44.205.64.79:443: i/o timeout
```

This is my Task Definition:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:...:task-definition/taskname_task:6",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "containername_container",
            "image": "username/repo",
            "cpu": 0,
            "links": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "containername_container-8888-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8888,
                    "hostPort": 8888,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "command": [],
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [],
            "dnsServers": [],
            "dnsSearchDomains": [],
            "extraHosts": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/taskname_task",
                    "awslogs-region": "ap-southeast-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "taskname_task",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 6,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.extensible-ephemeral-storage"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "2048",
    "ephemeralStorage": {
        "sizeInGiB": 21
    },
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "...",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::...:root",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom",
            "value": "ecs-console-v2"
        },
        {
            "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:stackId",
            "value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:...:stack/ECS-Console-V2-TaskDefinition-.../..."
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm new to ECS and AWS also. I have try the request `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/username/repo/manifests/latest` in the error of Task Container above and received this:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"username/repo","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

Is it about the request docker.io configured? I have done a lot of research but not figure anything out.

Comment: Does it work if you run `docker pull username/repo` from your local computer? Without telling us the actual docker image you are trying to use all we can do is guess at what your problem might be.

Comment: It works normally on `pull` and starts with container. I have updated the solution I tried, it works but I don't know why.

Comment: It sounds like you were deploying Fargate to a VPC subnet that didn't have Internet access, or you were not enabling public IP in the Fargate settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dockerhub` image from within `Amazon ECS Tasks` 
The format of `Dockerhub` image would be `[registry-url]/[namespace]/[image]:[tag]`, you do not need `registry-url` for `Dockerhub` as the docker client assumes `Dockerhub` if one is not specified 
Alternatively `Docker` official images should be present on [ECR public](https://gallery.ecr.aws/docker/) in addition to Dockerhub so you can reference the ECR public repositories instead from within the ECS Tasks
Now Fargate uses the awsvpc  network mode so essentially there are two options to run the task in `Fargate`:

- If the task is being run inside a public subnet, then `Auto assign Public IP` must be enabled and we need to ensure that public subnet route table has `Internet Gateway` for internet connectivity to be able to pull the container image from public docker repository
- If the task is being run from a private subnet then `Auto assign Public IP` must be disabled and we need to ensure that private subnet route table has an associated `NAT Gateway` allowing the task inside private subnet to pull the container image from public docker repository

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I used the image in Docker Hub public repository and the default tag is latest tag so I just simply put `"image": "username/repo",` inside `containerDefinitions`. The requested URL shows correctly but I don't know why there is an error `UNAUTHORIZED`.

Comment: Are you able to pull that dockerhub image from your machine?

Comment: Yes, normally. I have changed to **EC2** App environment and everything works fine. I still don't know why.

Comment: Do you have any concern with using ECR public repo with Fargate, can you test if that works?

Comment: For me the issue was with service security group which didn't allow outbound traffic. 

I'm using Terraform and for some reason it ignored rule definitions under service definition.